# Using variables in values YAML file

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm wondering what is the best way to pass input into a **values.yaml** file using a template.

I have a parent chart (called **myapp** for this example) defined which has the following dependencies:

**myapp/requirements.yaml**

```
dependencies:
- name: internaldep
  condition: internaldep.enabled
  repository: file://../internaldep
  version: 0.1.0
- name: kafka
  condition: kafka.enabled
  repository: https://charts.bitnami.com
  version: 6.1.6
```

In my case, both the **internaldep** chart (which spins up an internal app used by my company) and the **kafka** chart (maintined by Bitnami [here](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/kafka)) have a dependency to Zookeeper.

Because of this, **both** charts *in their own right* spin up Zookeeper by having a dependency within their respective charts, as such:

**kafka/requirements.yaml** and **internaldep/requirements.yaml**

```
dependencies:
- name: zookeeper
  version: 5.1.X
  repository: https://charts.bitnami.com
  condition: zookeeper.enabled
```

In order avoid spinning up two Zookeeper installations, I opted to just spin up one Zookeeper, and use that one instance for both apps as such:

**myapp/requirements.yaml**

```
dependencies:
- name: internaldep
  condition: internaldep.enabled
  repository: file://../internaldep
  version: 0.1.0
- name: kafka
  condition: kafka.enabled
  repository: https://charts.bitnami.com
  version: 6.1.6
+ - name: zookeeper
+   version: 5.1.X
+   repository: https://charts.bitnami.com
+   condition: zookeeper.enabled
```

I've run into a problem. The **kafka** chart determines the Zookeeper servers to use based on the following code block:

```
- name: KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
  {{- if .Values.zookeeper.enabled }}
  value: {{ template "kafka.zookeeper.fullname" . }}
  {{- else }}
  value: {{ .Values.externalZookeeper.servers | quote }}
  {{- end }}
```

Since I'm setting `.Values.zookeeper.enabled` to `false` (because I only want to use **one** Zookeeper installation for both apps), this means I **must** pass in the DNS names where Zookeeper can be found via `.Values.externalZookeeper.servers`.

However, when I try to do this in the **values.yaml** file:

```
kafka:
  externalZookeeper:
    servers: {{ .Release.Name }}-kafka-headless
```

I receive the error:

```
error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 82: did not find expected key
```

Is there a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend deploying multiple helm releases and linking them together with their values. Using helm dependencies you run into issues like this. I would generally not recommend relying on the dependency/requirement feature of helm for anything but but simple test installations. For production environments it's IMO way better to decouple your your application into multiple helm releases, which you can deploy and even switch out independently.

And to answer your question: to my knowledge there is no good way of doing what you want.